# Zebra label printing using php

Tags: php, zebra-printers

Can anyone help me with this project?

I have a format of a label that I want to make.
I tried looking through google with no luck. I have been searching for a day now.
It is a label for shipping that states the contents of the package and other data.
It does not need to have a bar code.
How can I make the format? Can i do it in PHP? Or can I do it in a separate software and then access it through PHP.

How can I do this?
How can I put data into it?
Finally, how can I print it?

Comment: What operating system will the PHP script be running on, and is the printer directly attached to the server, or is it attached to the network?  Are the drivers / CUPS PPD files installed on the server?

Comment: I did it! with qz-print though

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of questions here, and I don't know that they are all great for the StackOverflow format.  Hopefully this information helps.

To design the label, look up 'zpl manual' on Google to learn the design language.  There are a few 'complete label' designs at the beginning of the manual. Alternatively, you can download 'zebra label designer' which helps you design and print labels to Zebra printers.

If you need to print programmatically, you'll need to establish a connection with the printer.  Typically your printer will be on the network or it will have a USB connection with a printer.  In either case, you'll want to send the label ZPL data directly to the printer so that it prints.

Comment: yeah that... how can i send the data throu php?

Comment: i did it with qz-print. thanks for answering anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Cloud Print - connect Zebra to computer with running Google Chrome, learn https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/sendJobs and also try this: https://github.com/jamm/google-cloud-print

Comment: This doesn't answer *any* of the questions posed above, and is also blatant non-disclosed self-promotion.

Comment: @Charles I print to Zebra printers from PHP scripts through Google Cloud Print service (it's exactly answers the question) and I gave ready to use code to start doing same thing. This code is absolutely free so your "promotion" sounds silly.

Comment: @OZ_ are you able to send raw ZPL to the printers using this method? I have a similar problem where we need our web-app to be able to print labels on local Zebra Printers, unsure how to make this work with RAW ZPL data...

Comment: @user984976 yes. I open-sourced my own code to help all of you do the same. It's sad that some mean people as Charles downvotes my answer for that.

Comment: @OZ_ On the printer side are you using the Chrome browser extension to handle the print job or some other client software? I just read that the chrome extension doesn't accept raw data, it tries to apply some kind of conversion.

Comment: @user984976 it's enough just run the Chrome browser.